# Create jar file from command line

Tags: java, c, command-line, jar

I have the following directory hierarchy :

```
SigarTest
 src
    SigarTest
     .java files
 bin
    SigarTest
     .class files
```

Here,SigarTest is a package name. The root folder is in the bin folder of the jdk.
From there, im running the following command to create a jar file of my project -

```
./jar cfe temp.jar SigarTest.SigarMain SigarTest/bin/ tools.jar sigar.jar mongo-2.7.3.jar
```

where tools.jar, mongo-2.7.3.jar and sigar.jar are required and are in the same folder as root directory (bin folder of jdk). However, on running it, i get

```
ClassNotFoundException : SigarTest.SigarMain
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: jar cfe temp.jar SigarTest.SigarMain.class SigarTest/bin.... try his

Comment: @AlpeshPrajapati : Isnt that same as what i've done ?

Comment: you have not added .class after SigarTest.SigarMain...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [**`-C` *dir*** option](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html) which

> Temporarily changes directories (`cd` *dir*) during execution of the `jar` command while processing the following *inputfiles* argument.

If you execute the `jar` command in your question and list the contents of temp.jar, you will see output similar to the following:

```
$ rm -rf temp.jar
$ jar cfe temp.jar SigarTest.SigarMain SigarTest/bin/ tools.jar sigar.jar mongo-2.7.3.jar
$ jar tf temp.jar
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
SigarTest/bin/
SigarTest/bin/SigarTest/
SigarTest/bin/SigarTest/SigarMain.class
tools.jar
sigar.jar
mongo-2.7.3.jar
$ java -jar temp.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: SigarTest/SigarMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SigarTest.SigarMain
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Note that having SigarTest/bin in temp.jar is incorrect. Executing temp.jar throws the `ClassNotFoundException` since `SigarMain` is in package `SigarTest.bin.SigarTest`. Now consider the following `jar` command that uses the **`-C` *dir*** option:

```
$ rm -rf temp.jar
$ jar cfe temp.jar SigarTest.SigarMain -C SigarTest/bin/ . tools.jar sigar.jar mongo-2.7.3.jar
$ jar tf temp.jar
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
SigarTest/
SigarTest/SigarMain.class
tools.jar
sigar.jar
mongo-2.7.3.jar
$ java -jar temp.jar
```

`SigarMain` is in the correct package and executing temp.jar does not throw a `ClassNotFoundException`.

Comment: Btw, when u do -C, is the directory changed for only the files following the directory name or all values that follow that name ? According to this, it should be the latter right ?

Comment: The documentation is a little confusing on this. From some testing, I found that it was just the one file following, which explains why in `-C SigarTest/bin/ . tools.jar`, `SigarMain.class` is taken from `SigarTest/bin/` and `tools.jar` is taken from the directory `jar` was executed in. You can also specify `-C` multiple times.