# How do I use a dependency for Servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, dependency-injection, three-tier

I have a businessLogic layer and I want to use it in servlet, but anything I do it throws me an error:

```
@WebServlet("/Servlet")
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       IPersonService service;
 
    public Servlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void init(){
        service=new PersonService();
    }
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        service.getAll();
    }
```

PersonService is from an external project and I have reference. I test it in its own project and it works, but when I want to use it in servlet it gives me a strange error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: LBusinessInterfaces/IPersonService;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields
```

Comment: Do you have the jar containing the IPersonService class inside WEB-INF/lib in your deployed webapp? That's where it must be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have your external dependency jar that contains your business interface (PersonService). into the servlet container. Should be either 'lib' folder of the container, or it should be found inside your projects 'WEB-INF/lib' folder.

Comment: how do i make a jar from my interfaces?

Comment: As you would do with usual java class files. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9941296/how-do-i-make-a-jar-from-a-java

Comment: Refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243442/create-jar-file-from-command-line

Comment: For different IDEs simply search on StackOverFlow